# Error while using both sparse_categorical_crossentropy and categorical_crossentropy in keras

Tags: python, keras, reshape, tf.keras

I have started training a basic MLP model on MNIST data taken from [here](https://datahack.analyticsvidhya.com/contest/practice-problem-identify-the-digits/). Below is my code for implementing the model.

```py
train = pd.read_csv(r"train.csv")
test = pd.read_csv(r"test.csv")
train_img_path = "./Images/train/"
test_img_path = "./Images/test/"
```

```py
train_img = []
for img in train['filename']:
    img_path = train_img_path+img
    image = imread(img_path)
    
    image = image/255
    train_img.append(image)
    
train_img = np.array(train_img) 

batch_size = 64
y_train = train['label']

from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical
#y_train = to_categorical(y_train)
```

```py
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(10, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dense(10, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dense(10, activation = 'softmax'))

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(train_img, y_train, epochs=20, batch_size=batch_size)
```

While trying to fit my model on this data I get error `InvalidArgumentError:  logits and labels must have the same first dimension, got logits shape [50176,10] and labels shape [64]` with `loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy'`.

There were suggestions to try with `loss='categorical_crossentropy'` after having one-hot encoded values and that also gives error `ValueError: Shapes (None, 10) and (None, 28, 28, 10) are incompatible`

I am confused on how I am getting the shape `[50176,10]` (though examples are 49000) in the error.
I guess I am missing something on shape. Can someone guide me where I am doing wrong and how to solve this.

**Edit**: I have modified my code as below to pick the data from `keras` `for_from_dataframe`. But I still get the same error.

```py
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

train_data = train_datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
    dataframe=train,
    directory='./Images/train',
    x_col='filename',
    y_col='label',
    weight_col=None,
    target_size=(28,28),
    color_mode='grayscale',
    class_mode='categorical',
    batch_size=64
)

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
#model.summary()
model.fit(train_data, epochs=20)
```

Comment: Did you try to add `Flatten()` layer to your model as the first layer?

Comment: Thanks. Just adding the `Flatten()` layer did the trick. Is that because I am passing image data and hence it should be used?

Comment: Yes, because your data is 3-dimensional including the depth of the image.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is in your model building code:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(10, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dense(10, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dense(10, activation = 'softmax'))
```

You are trying to feed images and its label to ANN which obviously gives error. Also there is no any inputs given in your model.

For images, CNN should be used instead of ANN.

```
import tensorflow as tf
model = Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, activation = 'relu', input_shape=(28,28,3)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(128, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
model.add(Dense(10, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dense(20, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dense(10, activation = 'softmax'))
```

If you have one-hot encoded your labels, use `categorical_crossentropy`. If your labels are numbers then use `sparse_categorical_crossentropy`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Just including `Flatten()` layer before `Dense()` worked. I hope image data can also be fed to MLP model.

Comment: @mockash CNN are better in performance than MLP for Image Classification. Better use CNN